How can I apply certain Xbox controller keybinds depending on the position of the analog/joysticks on Windows 10?
I'm looking to bind the following functionality to my Xbox Series S controller via Steam's controller input, for one game only:

Pressing the controller's X button actually presses K on the keyboard, but only while the left joystick is held leftwards (x axis < 0%)

Pressing the controller's X button actually presses Q on the keyboard, but only while the left joystick is centered / unheld (x axis ≈ 0%)

Pressing the controller's X button actually presses K on the keyboard, but only while the left joystick is held rightwards (x axis > 0%)


My questions:

Is Steam controller input functionality the best way to achieve this?

If so, how can I do it?

What would the feature be called - e.g, button chording, action layers...


I have tried using lots of software to achieve this (reWASD, XPadder, AutoHotKey, Steam, Logitech G Hub, Joy2Key) as well as lots of careful googling and had no luck. Any help is appreciated!
